# how get more than a bundle in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have problem to get more than a `Bundle` in a `Fragment`.

With my code I pass data from activity, but don't get value data in fragment.

ACTIVITY:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putIntegerArrayList("oki", hm);
bundle.putIntegerArrayList("okiquantitapizze", hm_quantitàpizze);

System.out.println("PERO:" + bundle);

MyListFragment myFragment = new MyListFragment();
myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.a, myFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

FRAGMENT:

```
try {
    bundle = getArguments();

    System.out.println("BUNDLES1:" + bundle);
    if (bundle != null) {
        strtext = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("oki");
        quantitàpizze=bundle2.getIntegerArrayList("okiquantitapizze");

        System.out.println("CAZZ:" + strtext);

        System.out.println("PRESO:" + quantitàpizze);
    }
} catch(Exception e){

}
```

Comment: what is `bundle2`?

Comment: In which method of fragment are you trying to get arguments?

Comment: @nikis yes, bundle2 was the problem....

Answer (score 0):

The question on how to pass more than one bundle is to put the second `Bundle` into the first. In order to do that you can use the `Bundle#putAll` method for that:

> Inserts all mappings from the given Bundle into this Bundle.

e.g.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
bundle.putAll(bundle2); // empty fields, but that's how it works
```

With that you can access every field in your `Fragment`. In your case it would look like this

```
 strtext = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("oki");
 quantitàpizze=bundle.getIntegerArrayList("okiquantitapizze"); // removed bundle2
```

See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putAll(android.os.Bundle)) for `putAll`.

Comment: Just curious why you wouldn't just use ```Bundle#getBundle```? Otherwise you will have to handle each individual object within the bundle, instead of the bundle itself

Comment: @SaikCaskey By using `putBundle` you would have one more call inside the Fragment to get the value. Between Activities it's the better way, but for Fragments it's usually not since you would want to let the parent Activity do the navigation handling.

Comment: But, simply, by using putAll, you will likely have to manage more variables - personally I would prefer to use the bundle structure, then you can foreach the bundle#keySet and then process each thing, instead of having to assign every value to a var. Obviously it's perfectly valid either way, I was just curious

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not exactly the answer to the issue but you can use this approach for setting arguments for Fragment

you can use newInstance method in your fragment

```
 public static MyListFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Integer> hm,ArrayList<Integer> hm_quantitàpizze) {

        Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
        bundle.putIntegerArrayList("oki", hm);
        bundle.putIntegerArrayList("okiquantitapizze", hm_quantitàpizze);
        MyListFragment fragment = new MyListFragment ();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }
```

And get the bundle in `onCreateView()` of your fragment

Make Fragment transaction in activity as below

```
    MyListFragment myListFragment = MyListFragment.newInstance(hm,hm_quantitàpizze);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_container,myListFragment ).commit();
```